# Numpy vectorize sum over indices

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a list of indices (list(int)) and a list of summing indices (list(list(int)). Given a 2D numpy array, I need to find the sum over indices in the second list for each column and add them to the corresponding indices in the first column. Is there any way to vectorize this?
Here is the normal code:

```
indices = [1,0,2]
summing_indices = [[5,6,7],[6,7,8],[4,5]]
matrix = np.arange(9*3).reshape((9,3))
for c,i in enumerate(indices):
    matrix[i,c] = matrix[summing_indices[i],c].sum()+matrix[i,c]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an almost* vectorized approach using [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
lens = np.array(map(len,summing_indices))
col = np.repeat(indices,lens)
row = np.concatenate(summing_indices)
vals = matrix[row,col]
addvals = np.add.reduceat(vals,np.append(0,lens.cumsum()[:-1]))
matrix[indices,np.arange(len(indices))] += addvals[indices.argsort()]
```

Please note that this has some setup overhead, so it would be best suited for `2D` input arrays with a good number of columns as we are iterating along the columns.

*: Almost because of the use of `map()` at the start, but computationally that should be negligible.

Comment: It gives me the error:
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
on the second line. 
Did you mean to write
    lens = np.array(list(map(len(summing_indices)))
?

Comment: @Aditya369 Try : `lens = np.array(map(len,summing_indices)).astype(int)`.

Comment: It gives me 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'map'

Comment: I understand what you're doing though.